# Where to start on a Speech recognizing app

Tags: ipad, ios, speech-recognition

The app i'm supposed to develop needs speech recognition.But as i've been doing iphone development only for 4 months,this is a tough ask.Could any one provide any pointers as to where i should start searching for info.Also it consists of a group of ipads connected via wifi.I know this question is asking many things at once,but all i need are some pointers in the right direction,as i don't have time to spend knocking wrong doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited information provided I would recommend that your first step would be to find a suitable Voice Recognition framework for iOS unless you want to roll out your own implementation, which I would not recommend if you are not familiar with the field and different algorithms involved.

A quick search produced two such products: [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) and [CeedVocal SDK](http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocalsdk/). Of course without knowing the specifics such as what languages you need to support and if you need it for commercial use, it will be hard to provide specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks,I was just looking at the OpenEars website before coming to this post.

Comment: English is the language that we need to support,and yes it is for commercial use.

Comment: @Mithun Madhav I haven't used it, but it is free and based on the FAQ, it seems that you can use it for commerical use. Also I would look at the Carnegie Mellon University speech site that OpenEars links to, because there is a lot of information there about Speech Recognition http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/hephaestus.html and http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/

Comment: Thanks again.Any info on how to do the wifi connection.Im talking about one ipad recognizing the speech and triggering reponses on atleast 10 other ipads listening to it.

Comment: @Mithun Madhav I unfortunately am not an iOS developer, but I would recommend looking at the sample code from the iOS Developer Reference page. The samples page includes several dealing with Networking http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code . The SimpleNetworkStreams sample looks interesting. The following links lists everything including samples on the Reference Site that deal with Networking http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Networking%20%26amp%3B%20Internet

Comment: @Waleed : Ah.Ok.Thanks for all your effort